# How to load data into array?

Tags: java, arrays

There is a section in my assignment where I have to load these items into an array using a constructor and helper method. This is what it asks exactly:

*The Warehouse class contains an array of inventory Items that are currently in stock. The array is populated using a helper method that loads the data.*

*The Warehouse class will have 2 instance variables: the number of inventory items and an array to hold the inventory items. Assume that the maximum number of types of items is 60. You will need to add this information to the class.*

*The constructor will be used to initialize these variables by loading the data that is hardcoded and included in the class.*

How can go about doing this? This is what I have so far:

```
 public class Warehouse

 //instance variables
 {private int numOfInvItems;
 private int inventoryItems[] = new int[60];

 //the constructor
 public Warehouse ()
 {numOfInvItems = 5;
 inventoryItems = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0};

 }


//helper method
/**
 * This is the hardcoded data to be loaded into the instance variables.  
 */
public int loadData()
{

    //("A11111", "Widgets", 30, 50, 70, 2.50, 20, 50);
    //("B22222", "Gadgets", 10, 20, 0, 4.00, 50, 100);
    //("C33333", "Trinkets", 100, 20, 35, 3.75, 80, 150);
    //("D44444", "Pickets", 0, 100, 20, 8.35, 25, 75);
    //("E55555", "Sockets", 200, 300, 150, 1.00, 200, 400);
    // number of items is 5;

    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Edit: Please ignore the 0s put into the array, I just put that as a test.

Comment: Basically, you are asking how to initialize arrays.  Any good Java tutorial or textbook will explain this.  Alternatively, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/404/creating-and-initializing-arrays#t=201702260500209921825.  When you have finished reading, you should know what to do.

Comment: The other thing to note is that your requirements state that `inventoryItems` should be an array of inventory items.  You have declared an array of `int`.  Have you written the class to represent an inventory item (yet?).

Comment: No I didn't do that yet. Should I change it to a String? Also how can I initialize the first array for example? Would it be like inventoryItems[] = {"A11111", "Widgets", 30, 50, etc..};

Comment: You need to do that *first*.  You (probably) can't write the code to declare and initialize the array of that class unless you have written the class.  But seriously, this should all be covered in your lecture notes, textbook, whatever.

Comment: No ... it wouldn't be like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some hints:

1. Code the class that is going to represent an inventory item.
2. It needs field, getters (and maybe setters) and a constructor
3. The declaration of the array will look like this:

   ```
     private NameOfYourClass[] inventoryItems
   ```
4. The initialization can look like this

   ```
         = new NameOfYourClass[] {
                new NameOfYourClass(/* constructor arg list */),
                new NameOfYourClass(/* constructor arg list */),
                new NameOfYourClass(/* constructor arg list */)
         };
   ```

If that doesn't make sense, please go back to your textbook, etc and READ.

Comment: Okay thanks I actually did make the inventory class and I named it "Item". So for the instance variable in the Warehouse class I initialized it like this: private Item[] inventoryItems;... So in the load data method, am I supposed to go like  inventoryItems = new Item();.. and inside the brackets I put the data? Thanks!

Comment: I ran into a compile error where it says there is a lossy conversion error from double to int. Do you know why this is? In the item class I specifically declared the variables with the correct data type.

Comment: Ask a new question, including the specific code that you are asking about, and the complete compiler error message.

Comment: Actually, don't bother.  Instead, compare what you have done with what I said you should do (step #4).  They are NOT equivalent.  Look where the curly brackets are.

Comment: Okay I did it exactly how you showed and the compile error says "incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int" and highlights the first double value "2.50".... Sorry I can't ask another question because it says I have reached my limit.

Comment: If I take out the double value and replace it with an int it does compile. I'm not sure why this is.

Comment: Carefully check the types  and the order of the arguments you have declared in the constructor against the types of the values you are passing.  I expect you are trying to pass a floating point value as the value of an `int` argument.

Comment: *"Sorry I can't ask another question because it says I have reached my limit."* - Yea.  StackOverlow is limiting your question-asking because of your your "poor record"; e.g. downvotes.  It is what happens when people don't read or ignore the advice on how to ask decent questions.

Comment: Awesome I fixed it, thank you! So now I just put loadData() in the Warehouse constructor and I would be done, right? What should I put as the return value in the loadData method?

Answer (score 0):

First, instead of this line, `inventoryItems = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0}`, you will want to call the `loadData()` method, because you don't want to set your inventory to just have these five zeros, you want it to have the data that you add to it in the `loadData()` method. You will need to set up the `loadData()` method to add to your instance variable that is an array for the inventory. Given this, you will also want to remove the `numOfInvItems = 5` because the size of the inventory will be dependent on what you load into the `loadData()` method.

So with the concept of just having the constructor call the helper method, you just need to set up the helper method properly then. So you will be wanting to change/update your instance variable `inventoryItems`, but don't forget to keep track of the size as well.

If you need any more help or more specific things I'd be glad to help!

Comment: So how can I initialize each array if they contain both numbers and strings? I forgot how to do that.

Comment: An array can only hold one data type, so, if you aren't doing any manipulation within the array itself, (I.e. adding elements together), which wouldn't be logical for an inventory anyways, then you can just make an array of strings, which can hold letters and numbers. You will just have to add the numbers as strings, for example "30" instead of 30.